# Does `git stash push` not stash unstaged changes?

Tags: git

Does `git stash push` not stash unstaged changes?

```
$ touch testfile
$ git stash push
No local changes to save
```

Why does it work for staged changes now?

```
$ git add testfile 
$ git stash push
Saved working directory and index state WIP on mybranch: e5c1660  add note
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git stash` code saves, by default,<sup>1</sup> exactly and only the *tracked* files.  An untracked file is a file that is in the work-tree, but not in the index.  Such a file is not going to be in the next commit you make, if you make a commit right now, whether or not the file is listed in a `.gitignore`.

Once the file *is* in the index, it *will* be in the next commit you make, whether or not it is listed in a `.gitignore`.  So, once you `git add testfile`, there is something in the index that does not match something in `HEAD` and `git stash` is willing to make commits from both the index and work-tree.  The `git stash` command (with no extra options) will save<sup>2</sup> the index and work-tree if either one differs from `HEAD`, but will do nothing if both exactly match `HEAD`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm deliberately ignoring, here, the option to run `git stash save -u` or `git stash save -a`.  These make a stash that includes three commits instead of two.  It also changes the cleaning action that `git stash save` executes.  A later `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` of a three-commit stash works somewhat differently from the later `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` of a two-commit stash, as well, though this answer does not address the later `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` at all.

<sup>2</sup>The *push* verb in `git stash push` is simply the opposite of the `pop` verb in `git stash pop`; it has nothing to do with `git push`.  Back in the old days, `git stash` did not have a `push` sub-command.  Some people noted that `git stash` had some weird syntactic issues *and* this asymmetry—pop without push—so eventually `git stash` acquired a `push` sub-command with better syntax and the ability to stash just some subset of files.

Note that when using the subset feature, the `I` and `W` commits you mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54318663/1256452) are still full snapshots; it's just that the `W` snapshot only *adds* the specified subset files, and then the subsequent `git reset` + checkout that `git stash` runs only resets the specified subset as well.  There was a very nasty, data-destroying bug in this new feature for several Git revisions: `git stash push <subset>` would save the subset, then reset too many files.

Comment: Thanks. "whether or not the file is listed in a .gitignore", do you mean a file listed in .gitignore is also an untracked file?

Comment: By "the subsequent  git reset + checkout that git stash runs ", do you mean `git stash pop` is implemented by invoking git reset and git checkout?

Comment: By "when using the subset feature", do you mean that  `git stash push` always stores only  the difference of the working tree or index from HEAD, and `git stash pop` always apply only the difference?

Comment: (1) No: a file listed in `.gitignore` is just listed there if it's tracked. If it's *untracked*, the entry in `.gitignore` tells Git: *don't complain about it, and don't auto-add the file when I say "add all files".* It also gives Git the ability to *overwrite or remove* the file in some cases (it means "this file is not very valuable"). (2) No: the `git reset` + checkout is the last part of `git stash save` / `git stash push`: having committed the files, Git *wipes them out*, replacing them with the versions from `HEAD`.

Comment: (3): No: `git stash push`, because it has better syntax, allows you to say: *only save, then reset, some specific set of files, rather than all tracked files.*