# Why git stash creates two commits

Tags: git, git-stash

This is a history graph with a stash ref using `git log --graph --all refs/stash`:

```
*   commit e5e6f3db57db6237a4334dc69a9a229f1cd7bd82 (refs/stash)
|\  Merge: 2a1a05a e918d31
| | Author: user <xxx@yyy.com>
| | Date:   Sun Jan 12 12:27:13 2020 +0000
| | 
| |     On master: some stash comment
| | 
| * commit e918d315535c6c6ade2dfb0538039d527dd0cd6e
|/  Author: user <xxx@yyy.com>
|   Date:   Sun Jan 12 12:27:13 2020 +0000
|   
|       index on master: 2a1a05a init
| 
* commit 2a1a05a258d3877ed1f6d32dfd57ae1941530418 (HEAD -> master)
  Author: user <xxx@yyy.com>
  Date:   Sun Jan 12 12:09:51 2020 +0000

      init
```

Why commit `e5e6` is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a [regular stash commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_discussion)

> A stash entry is represented as a commit whose tree records the state of the working directory, and its first parent is the commit at HEAD when the entry was created.
>   The tree of the second parent records the state of the index when the entry is made, and it is made a child of the HEAD commit.
>
> The ancestry graph looks like this:
>
> ```
>        .----W
>       /    /
> -----H----I
> ```
>
> where H is the HEAD commit, I is a commit that records the state of the index, and W is a commit that records the state of the working tree.

As explained by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in "[How is a stash entry a child commit of HEAD commit and index's commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54318765/6309)"

> the stash entry represented by commit `W` and commit `I`, but `W` suffices to find `I`.
>   Either of `W` or `I` suffices to find `H`, and git stash will find all three commits automatically.

See also [this answer about restoring a stash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51276389/6309).

Comment: Ok, now I am thinking why the second commit is a merge?

Comment: @kan I have edited the answer and added a link to more explanation about a stash entry.